# How change font in menu xml file?

Tags: java, android, fonts, menu

How change in xml ( no inside .java) with my custom font?

I have this but programmaticaly no, because i think that in my situation is not a good idea.

**main menu.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Inicio"
    android:icon="@mipmap/home"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Equipo"
    android:icon="@drawable/box24"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Crono"
    android:icon="@drawable/timer"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/four"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Vídeos"
    android:icon="@drawable/vvideo"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/five"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Mapa"
    android:icon="@drawable/mapfinal"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

After, I use all of this in Main activity like:

`mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);`
        `mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.menu_main, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {`

```
        @Override
        public void onMenuItemSelected(@IdRes int i) {
```

.
.
.
.

UPDATE:

`public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {`

```
BottomBar mBottomBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    }

    mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
    mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.menu_main, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMenuItemSelected(@IdRes int i) {
```

.
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have direct control over fonts via menu resources. Whatever is *using* the menu resource *might* give you control over fonts, but that is not required.

Comment: so..what? In .java how ? I have implement in a line (menu.menu_main). How can change the font?

Comment: @RfMvs: "In .java how ?" -- since I have no idea what `BottomBar` is, I cannot answer that. Talk to whoever wrote `BottomBar`.

Comment: @RfMvs: I still do not know what `BottomBar` is. There does not appear to be a class by that name in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

> Use Typeface in OnCreateMenu in your activity or use CustomTypeface in menu xml layout
>
> Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Arial.TTF");